# Could you help me. How can I make real-time changing value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom

I have a code:

```
var appearScroll = function(){
    let fline = document.getElementById("skills__listone");
    var skills = document.getElementById("skills");
    var baselocation = 0;
    fline.style.opacity = 0;
    var distance = window.pageYOffset;
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        for (i = 0 ; i < 800; i++){
            i = distance;
            console.log(distance);
        }
    })
```

As you can see, I sent the value of variable to the console log and it should change, when I scroll. But it doesn't work, and the value changes only when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you invoke the `appearScroll` function somewhere, this function only ever reads the value of `window.pageYOffset` *once*.  Then on the `scroll` event your event handler function logs that one value to the console (up to 800 times for some reason?).

In order to read a new value in the `scroll` event, you have to read that value in that event handler.  For example:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
})
```

(Logging the same value 800 times also seems unnecessary of course.  Though I suppose it's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do with the various other values involved that aren't being used.)

Comment: I want to changes some properties of class, when window.pageYOffset < 500. I don't know how can I realize it. I tried to makt cycle, but it was infinity. I tried to use "if" but It can see changes after refreshing the page

Comment: @jukeer: I imagine in this `scroll` handler function then you'd want something like `if (window.pageYOffset < 500) { /* do something */ }`.  You can use an `if` construct to examine a condition and perform and action.

Comment: I tried to do this, but it works only one time for example, we use "click" event instead of "scroll". The property of css chanhes only when I clicked one time. Consider the situation at the moment offset is 600, I clicked, and there are nothong happened, after this I make an offset 400 (window.pageYOffset < 500), it doesn't works because condition have been over

Comment: @jukeer: Can you edit the question to provide a more complete example demonstrating this specific problem?  You can include HTML, JavaScript, and CSS in a runnable code snippet or at least link to an off-site example using something like jsFiddle.